# What is the time complexity of this function?

Tags: c++

I would like to ask about the time complexity of my function. Below is my function written in C++.

```
void List::swap(List& other)
{
     List temp;
     Iterator r = begin();
     Iterator i = other.begin();

     while(!i.equals(other.end()))
     {
         temp.push_back(i.position->data);
         i = other.erase(i);
     }

     while(!r.equals(end()))
     {
         other.push_back(r.position->data);
         r = erase(r);
     }

     r = temp.begin();
     for(r; !r.equals(temp.end()); r.next())
     {
         push_back(r.position->data);
     }
}
```

The function purpose is swapping elements of two linked lists. The exercise requires this function to be executed in O(1) time. Because I used 3 loops, I wasn't sure how exactly to count the time complexity for mine function.

Comment: Well, how many times is each operation executed?  Do any of the individual operations have a time complexity greater than O(1)?

Comment: Generally if you have a loop that loops a non-constant number of times, the complexity is not `O(1)`

Comment: If you want to swap the contents of two containers in constant time then you definitely don't want to loop over their elements. Think about how else you could swap the contents without even touching the elements.

Comment: First of all, this is an implement for singly linked list. Second, I don't implement a get size function because the exercise said that. More detail about this. My approach is that transfer the element from the second list to the temp list and delete the content of the second at the same time. Then move the content from the first one to the second one and also delete the content from the first. Finally, take out the content from the temp and put it back in the first. In my book, it said that push_back and delete (or erase) will take only  O(n) time or precisely O(1) time.

Comment: @Spincel: in a singly-linked list, each list usually has a pointer to the first element (which points to the second element and so on).  If you exchange this pointer in the two lists, you will exchange the contents, right? ;-)

Comment: There is an answer to that, so thanks you too. I wasn't really think about that at the first time. However, I want to know if my algorithm still generate O(1) time or will it be different.

Comment: Congrats! You've invented yet another pervert way of swapping two lists. You actually swap them by using assignment `a=b; b=c; c=a;` !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about the Big Oh notation , the complexity would be the max(complexity of loop1, complexity of loop2, complexity of loop3) . Since you are using 3 loops the complexity will definitely not be O(1). 
Hint: Since these are linked lists, you only need to swap the head pointers.

Comment: What is every loop has O(1), so does that mean the max is O(1) too?

Comment: @Spincel every loop is O(n), not O(1)

Comment: @SethCarnegie My mistake, so with loop, the time should be O(n), right?

Comment: @Spincel at least (I think it's really `O(n + m)` which is even worse). But you're doing a lot of unnecessary work. This function can be implemented in O(1) time (no loops or anything like that)

Comment: Yes, the complexity will be linear, which means O(n) or as @SethCarnegie explained in detail, O(n+m)

Answer (score 2):

You can think of order of growth as the upper bound for a problem's complexity.

The first while loop is O(other.size())

The second while loop is O(this.size())

The third loop is O(other.size())

So the total complexity is O(2 * other.size() + this.size()), which more correctly described in O notation as O(m + n) or O(n), depending on whether the size of the two lists are independent from one another.

Comment: Actually it would be `O(other.size() * 2 + this.size()) = O(n)`, no?

Comment: @Seth: That assumes that the two list sizes are dependent.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth what does that mean?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I just invented the terminology.  But in the sense that you can only reduce it to a single independent variable if `m` can be expressed as `kn + c`.  If `m` and `n` are independent, then you need them both in the big-O expression.

Comment: The `* 2` is a constant factor, so you can skip it (i.e. `2 * n` and `n` will both scale exactly the same based on `n`).

Comment: @Mario which is why I said `= O(n)`.

Comment: O(m+n) is the most technically correct answer.  Because you cannot determine from the code whether the two lists are independent sizes.

Comment: But anyone who cares about the complexity of things would look at that and be like, ok, degree 1 cost, that's something I do/don't want to further optimize.

Comment: That's "oversimplified", because you'd lose the dependency on `m` (unless both are the same or nearly the same; i.e. you treat it as constant and directly dependant).

Comment: The list will have independent size but I actually don't really care about the size as the exercise does not tell me to implement get_size.

Comment: @Spnicel: You do care about the size, because that's `n` (or `m`).

Comment: Is there any way to check that in Visual Studio by debugging?

Comment: @SethCarnegie If size of first list is n and size of the other list is m, you need to say O(n+m). (consider where the scenario where m is increased heavily, but n stays the same. Obviously, execution time will increase).

You could however get around all this by redefining n as `n = size of largest list`. If this is done, the complexity would be O(n).